# If a polynomial ring is a finite flat module over some subring, is that subring itself a polynomial ring?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, homological-algebra

A question motivated by [If a polynomial ring is a free module over some subring, is that subring itself a polynomial ring?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1745649/if-a-polynomial-ring-is-a-free-module-over-some-subring-is-that-subring-itself.) and [If a polynomial ring is finite free over a subring, is the subring polynomial?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/282780/if-a-polynomial-ring-is-finite-free-over-a-subring-is-the-subring-polynomial).

Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field of characteristic zero (for simplicity),  and let $A$ be a $k$-subalgebra of a polynomial ring $B := k[x_1, \dotsc, x_n]$ such that $B$ is a flat $A$-module of finite type.

Then, must $A$ also be a polynomial ring?  It's true if $n=2$ (see [Regular subrings of a polynomial ring](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.ojm/1200773129) by Masayoshi Miyanishi for a proof).

If not, could we classify all such $A$ ?

Comment: Have you tried taking standard counter-examples to Luroth's problem in dimension $3$? There are subfields $K$ of $k(x_1, x_2, x_3)$, with $k(x_1, x_2, x_3)/K$ of finite degree, such that $K \not \cong k(y_1, y_2,y_3)$. Perhaps you could find one such that $k[x_1, x_2,x_3]$ is flat over $K \cap k[x_1, x_2,x_3]$. The other keyword you should know besides "Luroth" is that a variety with such $K$ as a function field is called "unirational, but not rational".

Comment: Thinking harder: For finitely generated modules, flat = projective. Copying the part of Neil Strickland's answer to my question then shows that A is regular. Conversely, if B is a polynomial and is finite over some regular subring A, then B will be flat over A by the miracle flatness theorem. So the question is simply whether we can get a polynomial ring to be finite over a regular, non-polynomial, subring.

Comment: How much do you care that $k$ is algebraically closed?  I'd rather work with subrings of $\mathbb{Q}(x,y,z)/(x^3+y^3+z^3=3)$ than think about cubic 3-folds. (Note that Miyanishi assumes $k$-algebraically closed, so there might be two dimensional counterexamples over $\mathbb{Q}$.)

Comment: @DavidESpeyer Thank you for some hints!  I will think about it..

Comment: Is the answer known for $n\ge 3$ if we additionally assume $B$ is etale over $A$ ?